# Why is it important to use static_cast instead of reinterpret_cast here?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

[At a reply of a blog post of Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/17/10106259.aspx#10106771),

A questioner pointed out

> Raymond, I believe the C++ example is not correct since the position
>   of the base class subobject in the derived class is unspecified
>   according to ISO C++ 2003 Standard (10-3, page 168), and you assume
>   that the base class subobject is always at the beginning. The C
>   example would be fine in C++ too, so I'd stick with it.

Raymond replied

> [The code does not make this assumption. That's why it's important to
>   use static_cast instead of reinterpret_cast. Try it: Add a virtual
>   method to OVERLAPPED (so a vtable goes in front) and observe what the
>   compiler does. -Raymond]

I could guess after read his comments. Using static_cast is fine at the example but reinterpret_cast is not. Because reinterpret_cast is not convert vtable. Do I understand it rightly?
Though, if I use C-Style cast at there(not reinterpret_cast), could it also go wrong?

I re-read More Effective C++'s cast explanation to understand that. But there was no answer about that.

Comment: I'm not at all versed in C++, but my understanding is that a "reinterpret cast" means exactly what `*(destination_type *)&` would mean in C. Presumably "static cast" actually takes class relationships into account and allows the compiler to do non-trivial conversion work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Using static_cast is fine at the example but reinterpret_cast is not. Because reinterpret_cast is not convert vtable.

No, the problem is that the `reinterpret_cast` is completely oblivious about the inheritance. It will simply return the same address unchanged<sup>1</sup>. But `static_cast` *knows* that you're performing a downcast: i.e. casting from a base class to a derived class. Since it knows both types involved it adjusts the address accordingly, i.e., does the right thing.

Let's *pretend* our implementation lays out the hypothetical `OVERLAPPEDEX` class that has a virtual function like this:

```
+------+------------+------------------+-------------+
| vptr | OVERLAPPED | AssociatedClient | ClientState |
+------+------------+------------------+-------------+
       ^
       |
      ptr
```

The pointer we're given points to the `OVERLAPPED` subobject. `reinterpret_cast` would not change that. It would only change the type. Obviously, accessing the `OVERLAPPEDEX` class through this address would easily wreak havoc, because the locations of its subobjects are all wrong now!

```
       what we believe we have when we access OVERLAPPEDEX through the pointer
       +------+------------+------------------+-------------+
       | vptr | OVERLAPPED | AssociatedClient | ClientState |
+------+------+-----+------+-----------+------+------+------+
| vptr | OVERLAPPED | AssociatedClient | ClientState | <- what we actually have
+------+------------+------------------+-------------+
       ^
       |
      ptr
```

`static_cast` *knows* that to convert a `OVERLAPPED*` to `OVERLAPPEDEX*` it must adjust the address, and does the right thing:

```
 +------+------------+------------------+-------------+
 | vptr | OVERLAPPED | AssociatedClient | ClientState |
 +------+------------+------------------+-------------+
 ^
 |
ptr after static_cast
```

---

> Though, if I use C-Style cast at there(not reinterpret_cast), could it also go wrong?

A C-style cast is defined as the first one of the following that succeeds:

1. `const_cast`
2. `static_cast`
3. `static_cast`, then `const_cast`
4. `reinterpret_cast`
5. `reinterpret_cast`, then `const_cast`

As you can see, a `static_cast` is tried before `reinterpret_cast`, so in this case, a C-style cast would also do the right thing.

---

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/46642)

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Not guaranteed. There are very little guarantees about what happens on a `reinterpret_cast`. All implementations I know of will simply give out the same address unchanged.</sub>

Comment: Yes, my `convert vtable` was the very weird sentence. btw, Does C-style caster also know the inherit-relationship? Maybe it is not. But I have always used the C-style cast, even if I use C++. And I think it even worked well at the example. That's weird thing.

Comment: @Benjamin I added an explanation about C-style casts, and why it does work in this case. I would recommend against use them though, because it isn't always clear which of the alternatives is picked. A C-style case is a very blunt hammer.

Comment: Of course I will follow your recommend, because I understand it now. Thank you. Does your order of C-Style caster doing is standardized, though?

Comment: @Benjamin yes, that order is specified by the standard.

Comment: Also note a possible gotcha with the C-style cast: If the compiler can't determine that there's an inheritance structure (for example missing a header include) it will fall back to `reinterpret_cast`, failing in just the same way. This is yet another reason C-casts are dangerous.

Comment: I'm curious about your footnote. Does the standard allow for `reinterpret_cast` to change the value? How could that ever be useful? It seems like it flies in the face of what `reinterpret_cast` is designed to do.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: what do you think `reinterpret_cast` is designed to do? Yes, the standard allows it to change the value. The only guarantee you have is that if you `reinterpret_cast` back to the original type you get the original value. The intermediate value can be *anything*, as long as the implementation can retrieve the original from it. If you don't rely on the implementation-defined behaviour of `reinterpret_cast` that's all you can do with it: get an unspecified value of another type, and then retrieve the original from it.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I think Raymond had a mistake, though. The sentence `Add a virtual method to OVERLAPPED` should be `Add a virtual method to OVERLAPPEDEX`. If I add a virtual method to **OVERLAPPED**, there will be no problem even if I use reinterpret_cast. Am I right?

Comment: @Benjamin Oh, I didn't notice that. In that case it will probably work, (but the standard makes no guarantees). I wouldn't use it (because `static_cast` is *guaranteed* to work), but I guess it works on most implementations.