# Why does dynamic_cast exist?

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast, static-cast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular cast vs. static_cast vs. dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast)

I learned how static_cast works by this question.
[Why is it important to use static_cast instead of reinterpret_cast here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138730/why-is-it-important-to-use-static-cast-instead-of-reinterpret-cast-at-here)

But if static_cast does knows classes' inheritance-relationship, why does dynamic_cast exist? And when do we must use dynamic_cast?

Comment: I forget the specifics, but note that your `static_cast` example did not involve virtual. `dynamic_cast` is specifically used for virtual downcasting.

Comment: @Pubby Yes it is. But even if the example has a virtual method, static_cast works fine, am I misunderstanding?

Comment: *Any* sort of casting should be a rare event in C++, and a dynamic cast is probably one of the rarest among them, but as with most arcane C++ features, when you need it, you really need it.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with virtual methods.  You have a Base* pointer to an object of a derived class.  And like to access a member of that derived class.  Cast required, but how do you know that the cast is valid and that the object *actually* is of the expected derived class type?  dynamic_cast<> tells you, RTTI must be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I'll post a simple example of how they differ:

```
struct foo { virtual void fun() {} };
struct bar : foo {};
struct qux : foo {};

foo* x = new qux;
bar* y = static_cast<bar*>(x);
bar* z = dynamic_cast<bar*>(x);
std::cout << y; // prints address of casted x
std::cout << z; // prints null as the cast is invalid
```

If I understand correctly, `static_cast` only knows the type it's casting to. `dynamic_cast` on the other hand knows type being cast, along with the type being cast to.

Comment: This shows the `what` but OP is looking for the `why`.

Answer (score -1):

`dynamic_cast` returns NULL if the cast is impossible if the type is a pointer (throws exception if the type is a reference type). Hence, `dynamic_cast` can be used to check if an object is of a given type, `static_cast` cannot (you will simply end up with an invalid value).

Also, in some cases `static_cast` is not possible, e.g. with multiple inheritance:

```
class Base {};
class Foo : public Base { ... };
class Bar : public Base { ... };
class FooBar: public virtual Foo, public virtual Bar { ... };

FooBar a;
Foo & foo1 = static_cast<Foo &>(a); // Illegal, wont compile
Foo & foo2 = dynamic_cast<Foo &>(a); // Legal
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `static_cast` to virtual base is legal; it's the other way around that's illegal.